# Excel VBA column manipulation

Tags: excel, vba

I have very liitle experience and try to use examples to achieve what I need.
I have the following which concatenates my first step.

```
Do While ActiveCell <> "END"  'Loops until the active cell is blank.
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

What I then want to do is the next "set" of columns, eg column A and B hold the data A could be fixed as this is common to whole process. When the above VBA is run it fills column C. Then needs to delete column B, cut column A insert it after D and then insert a blank column just after that so the the concatenate process can take place, this is then carried out till the last column containing data, which is at the end of the sheet.
When first part of macro runs A and B joined in C.
_A____B_______C_______D______E_______F
ZZS____007____ZZS007___008_____009_____010
AS_____121____AS121____98_____23_______001
**_____END_____END_____END____END______END  

Columb B then deleted and empty column placed after C.

_A______B_______C_______D______E_______F

ZZS___ZZS007___008_**......**009_____010

AS____AS121____98__**......._23_______001
**______END_____END**......**END____END

Column A and C now joined in D.

_A______B_______C_______D______E_______F

ZZS___ZZS007___008__ZZS008_____009_____010

AS____AS121____98_____AS98_____23_______001

________END_____END____END______END____END

Column C now deleted and empty column added after D, etc to end of columns.

_A______B_______C_______D______E_______F

ZZS___ZZS007___ZZS008__009__**.....**_010

AS____AS121____AS98____23___**.....**_001

________END_____END____END__**.....___END

Comment: Since you are using Activecell it is hard to tell what you want to achieve. If you can illustrate before and after data, that would be great.

Comment: ZZS 007  008 009 010
ZZS 007  008 009 010
XM 006  007 008 009
LL 006  007 008 009
WG 006  007 008 009
XMO 006  007 008 009
ZZB 006  007 008 009
ZZB 006  007 008 009
4YA 118  119 120 121
4VN 006  007 008 009
VE 059  060 061 062
 END END END END END
So the above hopefully shows 6 colums, third column get concatenated from the first two columns, column two can then be deleted, the next column of numbers (TEXT)(leading zeros) is then concatenated in the empty column next to the row of number, unless of course you can conatenate the text and number into the number column, which means no deleting.

Comment: How do i add a selection of the spread sheet or columbs, i see the above has taken my formatting away.

Comment: Can you add the sample data in your question instead of comment. There is an edit selection right below the tag.

Comment: So column C is the joined column. have only shown two rows but this goes down some way but is note at the bottom of the column with END and the column go on to the right till the end of the sheet IV something.

Comment: What does the final data look like?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better approach for you:

```
  Dim iRow&, iCol&, zRow&, zCol&
  zRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  zCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
  For iCol = 2 to zCol ' or Do Until Cells(1, iCol) = ""? 
    For iRow = 1 To zRow ' or zRow-1?
      Cells(iRow, iCol) = Cells(iRow, 1) & Cells(iRow, iCol)
    Next iRow
  Next iCol
```

EDIT: (More Clearly:) I may be wrong, but I see you wanting to concatenate cells in column A to cells in all other columns.
You are proceeding as follows:

```
0) You start with A, B, C, D, ..
1) Inserting X to get A, B, X, C, D, ..
2) Copying B to X to get A, B, B', C, D, ..
3) Concatenating A&B' to get A, B, AB', C, D, ..
4) Deleting B to get A, AB', C, D, ..
```

I am suggesting that you:

```
0) You start with A, B, C, D ..
1) Replace B with A&B to get A, AB, C, D, ..
```

So 1 step is better than 4?
I'm sorry if I'm off base.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost, not very good at this,i've added this to underneath the first part of the vba shown above, so it does the fist instance of concatenate but then goes to column A and interupts the text I have there. My data starts from column K if that makes sense the first few columns holds other data pertanant to each Row.

Comment: I've added some more steps above to show what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks

Comment: @user3736010 - Doesn't my code give you what you want?  Or change `For iRow = 1 To zRow` to `For iRow = 1 To zRow-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This what i have ended up using, thanks for the feedback.

```
Sub concatenate_strings()  
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer  
Dim last_row As Integer, last_col As Integer  
Dim first_str As String, sec_str As String  

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate  

Range("A1").Select  
last_row = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row  
last_col = ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column  

With ActiveSheet  

For i = 1 To last_row  
        first_str = Cells(i, 1)
For j = 2 To last_col
        sec_str = Cells(i, j)
        Cells(i, j) = first_str & sec_str

    Next j

Next i
```